# Spacebar removes the letter in edit text on double tap

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

In my application I have edit texts, which must ignore spacebar every time the user enters it. I've written the next in my XML for edit texts in order for this to work:

```
android:digits="АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

So logically, it must only accept uppercase and lowercase russian letters, but when I double tap on spacebar, the letter in edit text is removed, as if I tapped backspace button. Why is this happening and what is the solution for it?

Comment: Something is missing in here, it doesn't make sense for spacebar to remove  letter on double or single tap. There must be something with your keyboard you are using in android or must have written something more than above given code for the implementation, which might be causing some issue.

Comment: @UMESH0492 I've checked it on emulator, I don't think that there is something wrong with its keyboard..

Comment: @UMESH0492 I've checked the settings of keyboard on emulator and its double-space period function was on, whic was the cause of this issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Pleasure to help, kindly upvote and update my answer below. So, that other user can also get to know. If they ever stuck with such kind of problem.

Comment: how do you remove that programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is missing in here, it doesn't make sense for spacebar to remove letter on double or single tap. There must be something with your keyboard you are using in Android or must have written something more than above-given code for the implementation, which might be causing some issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue with android:digit.
Find out that you need to add space in android:digit

```
android:digits=" АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
```

This solves my problem